# React-Native-Firebase - No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp() (on Android, despite correct setup)

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, react-native-firebase

React Native 0.71.3 + Typescript. Project uses ProGuard too, apparently.

I'm trying to integrade push notifications through cloud messaging. I've only tested it on Android.

I did all the steps required. What am I missing?

1. npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app
2. placed my google-services.json file in /android/app/ folder
3. Added `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'` at `/android/build.gradle`
4. Added apply plugin: `'com.google.gms.google-services'` at /android/app/build.gradle
5. npm install @react-native-firebase/messaging
6. npx react-native run-android to rebuild the project
   7)`import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';`in my App.tsx
7. For testing, I'm adding this function from the documentation

```
async function requestUserPermission() {
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  const enabled =
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

  if (enabled) {
    console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
  }
}
```

9. I call the function inside an useEffect() in App.tsx

Yet, despite all these steps, I keep getting

```
 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()
```

What am I missing? This is driving me insane.

Answer (score 1):

Because the function you copied is for iOS. Which required you add further initialization for [FIRApp configure];
For android, use this as guided:

```
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
  PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATIONS);
```